# Pandas filtering from a assigned column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to create a on the fly column using assign() function and I want to filter the value from that column. But pandas didn't recognize it.

```
df.assign(PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE = df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM / df.TXN_CNT_LTM).loc[df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE > 1]
```

The error message :
[image]

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you chain methods, you have to evaluate your dataframe in a `lambda` function:

```
df = (df.assign(PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE = df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM / df.TXN_CNT_LTM)
        .loc[lambda x: x.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE > 1])
```

Or with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = (df.assign(PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE = df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM / df.TXN_CNT_LTM)
        .query('PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE > 1')
```

Otherwise you have to do it in 2 steps:

```
df = df.assign(PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE = df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM / df.TXN_CNT_LTM)
df = df.loc[df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE > 1]
```

Comment: If I want to create a new column based on value on the assigned column, is it possible to do that? 

for example : 

`df.assign(PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE = df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM / df.TXN_CNT_LTM).loc[lambda x: x.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE > 0.5, 'IS_PROMO_SENSITIVE_LTM'] = 1`

Comment: @TimothyVarian. Yes it's possible to do that but other values will be NaN.

Comment: However, prefer `df.assign(PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE = df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM / df.TXN_CNT_LTM, IS_PROMO_SENSITIVE_LTM=lambda x: x.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE > 0.5)`

Comment: Actually it is not possible to create the column with your method above because `assign` returns a copy and `loc` works on that copy. The column assignment is therefore defined on this copy and not on your original dataframe.

Comment: I see, so in other words the only doable solution is creating real column in the original dataframe after that check its value to create another new column, isn't it?

Comment: Do you really need to create `PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE`? If not, you can simply use `df['IS_PROMO_SENSITIVE_LTM'] = df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM.div(df.TXN_CNT_LTM).gt(0.5).astype(int)`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use lambda function to chain method like this or use `query` method. See the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6]
})

df.assign(C=df['A']/df['B']).query('C > 0.3')
```

So, applied to your code will result in:

```
df.assign(
   PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE = df.PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM / df.TXN_CNT_LTM
).query('PROMO_TXN_CNT_LTM_RATE > 1')
```